# Which is correct: "I do not share your hate" or I do not share your hatred"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, nouns, synonyms

Which is the correct word to use in the following statement: *hate* or *hatred*?

> I do not share your **hate/hatred**.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What did you see in the dictionary ?

Answer (score -1):

Using the latter would make more sense

*I do not share your hatred for ____________* is one particular use of this type of statement.

Now if we were to use the words 'do not' as a contraction:

*I don't share your hate for __________* works equally as well.